# AngularJS $on - Re-subscribe a un-subscribed broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast

To un-subscribed from `$broadcast` in `$on`, one can do

```
var cleanUp = $rootScope.$on('myBroadcast', function(){ ... });
cleanUp();
```

Is there a way to re-subscribe once you have called `cleanUp()`?

Comment: The two lines of code you're presenting, executed in order would never execute the callback function for `myBroadcast`. What is the broader scope of your problem?

Comment: I know, those two lines are not to execute at the same time! What I want is basically to be able to un-register, and re-register whenever I want.

Comment: @Nico has given the correct answer then

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'll up vote it once the timer allows me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function foo () {
  return $rootScope.$on('myBroadcast', function(){ ... });
}
var cleanup = foo(); // listen

// somewhere down the road
cleanup(); // unlisten

// somewhere down the road
foo(); // listen again
```